# Convert from varchar to Nvarchar SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table  has a coulmn of type varchar I  need to  convert it to  Nvarchar    but it shows an error that I have to drop the table and recreate it :)  any advice  !!

Comment: How have you gone about trying to change the table? Through a script? Or a designer screen? Does it matter if you drop it and recreate it? Why the change in datatype?

Comment: If you are using the UI designer in SSMS, it will drop/create if the column is linked to some other table (referential) or has defaults or check constraints, or indexed filter etc.  It has a tendency to prefer the hammer approach (everything is a nail), but is justified sometimes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this not work:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_varchar_column NVARCHAR(32)
```

Comment: he wants to change to NVARCHAR()

Answer (score 5):

There is a setting that prevents SSMS from saving changes that requires tables to dropped and re-created.

You find the setting in Tools - Options - Designers.

[image]